# mean pixel subtraction for numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of grayscale images. The shape of the array is

```
imgs.shape
(100, 1, 300, 300)
```

which represents 100 images of grayscale (1 channel) and size 300x300.

I want to do mean pixel subtraction for this array.
That means I want to substract the mean pixel from all images.

I want the mean over all images.

For a single image that would be something like this:

```
X_mean = X.mean(0)
X -= X_mean
```

How can I do that for my array?

Comment: Do you want the *mean* over *all* images, or the mean for *each* image separately.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the mean over all images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its mean of one image at a time, we could compute the mean across the last two axes keeping the dimensions (that eases up code for subtraction later on) and simply subtract from original input, like so -

```
imgs -= imgs.mean(axis=(-2,-1),keepdims=1)
```

If its mean across all images, include the first axis too -

```
imgs -= imgs.mean(axis=(0,-2,-1),keepdims=1)
```

Note that the `mean` values would be by default as float values. So, if `imgs` is not of float type, we need to make a copy of `imgs` as float dtype and then subtract from it, or convert the `mean` values to be of same dtype as `imgs` and then subtract.

Sample run -

```
In [188]: imgs = np.random.randint(0, 255,(10,1,30,30))

In [189]: out = imgs - imgs.mean(axis=(0,-2,-1),keepdims=1)

In [190]: out.shape
Out[190]: (10, 1, 30, 30)

In [191]: out.dtype
Out[191]: dtype('float64')
```

Comment: is this the mean over all images?

Comment: @spore234 Its mean per image and then subtracted from each image.

Comment: it should be: 1. compute mean of all images 2. subtract this mean from each image. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: sorry, but I think this is wrong. For example, `x = np.random.randint(11,99,(100,1,300,300))` ,then both of your solutions lead to wrong shapes. the shape should be preserved, only the values should be 'centered'

Comment: @spore234 Not sure if I understood it correctly that comment. So, with `imgs -= imgs.mean(axis=(0,-2,-1),keepdims=1)`, the shape of `imgs` would be wrong? Or `imgs.mean(axis=(0,-2,-1),keepdims=1)` which would be basically a scalar for `imgs` : `(100, 1, 300, 300)` is wrong?

Comment: Let `imgs = np.random.randint(0, 255,(100,1,300,300))` be my data. This is a numpy array of shape (100,1,300,300) with int values from 0 to 255, like my real data. Could you please provide a working example for this? I think it is related to the integer problem you describe.